# Is there a type T in the standard library? IList<T> where T: class, new()

Tags: c#, .net

I'm testing a method which takes `IList<T> where T: class, new()`. For brevity, I'd like to test it with a type from the .NET standard library. However, I can't think of any which meet the conditions! Except for `List<List<T>>` - which I'd rather not use because manipulating collections of collections makes the test difficult to read.

Can you think of a type that meets the conditions? I don't want to add any new references.

Comment: If you want to test, why don't you create a very simple dummy class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `List<object>`  or `object[]` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are many classes that can be used although the best for you would be to create a small private class in your test class.

Simplest way would be using `object`-s:

```
var v1 = new object();
var v2 = new object();
```

If you want something that can be identified easier, you could use `System.Version`.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're missing what this means, you can provide any IList implementation that contains a T. T must be a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and must have a [parameterless constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so it could be any one of many classes, an `object` (as Marc pointed out, this is by far the simplest) or a `System.Windows.Forms.Button` or a `SqlConnection`.

Just create a new `List<object>`, `List<Button>` or a `List<SqlConnection>` to use any of these examples.